# ServiceStack Changing Default int value to -1 rather 0

Tags: servicestack

It is possible to change a default value for an intenger? 
When I'm posting a JSON message amd I'm not set up a int value, this one take by default 0, it's look like an issue for my application because this value is required. 
So can I change the default value of an int for -1 instead 0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can register a custom serializer for ints with:

```
JsConfig.IncludeNullValues = true;
JsConfig<int>.RawSerializeFn = i => i == 0 ? "-1" : i.ToString();

new Model { Int = 0 }.ToJson().Print(); // {"Int":-1}
```

Unfortunately it requires that you allow default values `(0)` to be serialized by specifying `JsConfig.IncludeNullValues = true` global configuration, but can be scoped with:

```
using (JsConfig.With(includeNullValues:true))
{
    new Model { Int = 0 }.ToJson().Print(); // {"Int":-1}
}
```

In the next v4.0.36+ of ServiceStack you will be able to specify a type-specific configuration, e.g:

```
JsConfig<int>.IncludeDefaultValue = true;
JsConfig<int>.RawSerializeFn = i => i == 0 ? "-1" : i.ToString();
```

Comment: Ok, I've been happy a bit fast. I need to use the value zero. Now every time I'm using 0 as value, it's converting it to -1. I just want to set the default value as -1 rather than zero, ONLY when I don't define my field value. It is possible? The only way that I'm seeing to do that seems to change my column for a string rather int, on this way I can handle "null". I really don't see a way to do this.

Comment: @Ben an `int` always has a value whether you explicitly define it or not, the default value is `0`. i.e. you wont be able to distinguish `0` that was explicitly set or not. Are you talking about `int?`.

Comment: Yes I'm talking about int. To be more explicit, I'm using this field to define a device type. And the first device type is 0, second 1... That's my issue, when I want to store a device I'm checking if the device type as been entering, checking the value 0 or -1 when nothing is entering. for manufacturing matter I need to keep zero as a valid entry, so I need to deal with that s*** The only way to see if nothing as been entering is to change the type for a string to detect null value as an error. Anyway, Thanks a lot for your help I will play like that